# What happens between the Initialize and Queryopen Events in a Lotus Notes Form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm suffering with some performance issues on opening documents, and I've identified that from the Initialize event to the QueryOpen event, is a lag of about 6.5 seconds.  I've done this by printing Timer() values at the start of those events.

The Initialize event has no code in it, and the same applies to the Global Initialize event.  I do have Script libraries in the global Options that have Initialize code that loads when the form is loaded, but the total time for them to initialise is under 0.3 seconds.

I've also carried out the same process with Debugger on, and after a quick flicker (presumable when the non-existent Initialize takes place), there is a lag of the same 6.5 seconds or so before it opens to step through QueryOpen.

Hence, I would like to know what happens in the 6.5 seconds between Initialize and QueryOpen.  I've considered things like loading default values.  Extra info: there are no embedded views in the form.

Comment: What about computed fields/computed text/computed for display fields?

Comment: What do you have on your form?  Any computed or computed-for-display fields doing DbLookup or DbColumn operations?

Comment: LOL!  @Duston won the race :-)

Comment: It's not my form, but I'll investigate.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if there's some horrific @DbLookups, as it's an old form that's been added to in a fairly "ad hoc" manner over the last 10 years.

Comment: Oh my!  69 @DbLookups - many of them No Cache.  Most of those identical, in hide-whens.  Time for some optimisation :)

Comment: Computed texts also slow down forms significantly, but you need to use more than a specific threshold of them...

Comment: I reduced 69 to 11, but it's still rather creaky.  Is there any advantage of computed for display fields over computed text, or would I be best just trying to get rid of as many of them as possible?